# Cannot subscript a value of type 'AnyObject' with an index of type 'String'

Tags: swift

i tried to get The (Name) value to a label

i used `resultLabel.text = !(jsonResult["name"])` but it returns an error

**Cannot subscript a value of type 'AnyObject' with an index of type 'String'**

[See my JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weMQl.png)

and does anybody know's how to get the data..

**My code ....**

```
    if let url = URL(string: "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=The+Raid&y=&plot=short&r=json") {

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in // URLSession.shared().dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) is now URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error)

        if error != nil {

            print(error)

        } else {

            if let urlContent = data {

                do {

                    let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject // Added "as anyObject" to fix syntax error in Xcode 8 Beta 6

                    print(jsonResult)

                    print(jsonResult["Title"])

                    resultLabel.text = (jsonResult["name"])

                    if let description = ((jsonResult["weather"] as? NSArray)?[0] as? NSDictionary)?["description"] as? String {

                        DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: {

                            self.resultLabel.text = description
                        }) 
                    }
                 } catch {

                    print("JSON Processing Failed")
                }
            }
         }
    }

    task.resume()

    } else {

        resultLabel.text = "Couldn't find weather for that city - please try another."

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting the result of JSON deserialization to `AnyObject` is the worst you can do.

First of all the unspecified JSON type is `Any` and since the type is supposed to be a dictionary, cast it to `[String:Any]`.

Further in Swift 3 the compiler **must** know all types which are subscripted

```
        let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: []) as! [String:Any]
            let name = jsonResult["name"] as? String
            print(name ?? "n/a")
            if let weather = jsonResult["weather"] as? [[String:Any]], !weather.isEmpty { 
                if let description = weather[0]["description"] as? String {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { // not sync !!
                        self.resultLabel.text = description
                    }
                }
...
```

PS: As always, `mutableContainers` is meaningless in Swift and meaningless anyway if the values are only read.

Comment: Well i appreciate your help.. but i have another simple question.. now your code worked but i need to show the (let name = jsonResult["name"] as? String) to a label.. idid (resultLabel = name) but it not work.. sorry im new to swift

Comment: Then write `self.resultLabel.text = name` in the dispatch block, name is extracted in the 2nd line.

Comment: Thank You so much mate... i ireally appreciate this help so much.. again thanks for your support